# How to correctly position the 3 circular images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a box in which I show the user's information. In this case, I need to add three parallel circular images to give the user more options.

I have added an example image to the end of the snippet of how I would like my three circular images to be displayed.

Below I have added an example snippet with what I have developed so far.

```css
.box.box-success {
    border-top-color: #00a65a;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-top: 3px solid #d2d6de;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.box-body {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.actividades {
    padding-right: 80px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    color: #5D6168;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.profile-user-img {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 3px solid #d2d6de;
}

.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.datosGenerales {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT';
    text-align: center;
    color: #5D6168;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.puesto {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    color: #5D6168;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="box box-success">
                
                <div class="box-body">

                    <div class="actividades">Activity</div>
                    <div class="box-body box-profile">
                        <img class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User profile picture"> 
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-lg-7 text">
                                <div style="display:inline-block; text-align: left;" >
                                <h1><img class="profile-user-img  img-circle" style="width: 60px;" src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User profile picture"></h1></div>
                                <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:18px;color: blue;"class="pb-4">Blank</div>
                                <br>
                                <div style="display:inline-block; " >
                                <h1><img class="profile-user-img img-circle" style="width: 60px;" src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User profile picture"></h1></div>
                                <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:18px;color: blue;"class="pb-4"> Blank</div>
                                <br>
                                <div style="display:inline-block; " >
                                <h1><img class="profile-user-img  img-circle" style="width: 60px;" src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User profile picture"></h1></div>
                                <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:18px;color: blue;"class="pb-4"> Blank</div>
                            </div>  
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="datosGenerales">Name</h2>
                    <div class="puesto">Description</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
```

The images that I want to add with the small 3 circles that are below the activity statement

**Example image:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to add  before `profile-user-img`
but there are many things to cleanup in your code. And don't use many h1 tags ( but this doesn't affect your problem )
Also if you don't use style="display:inline-block" you needn't `<br>`

```css
.box.box-success {
    border-top-color: #00a65a;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-top: 3px solid #d2d6de;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.box-body {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.actividades {
    padding-right: 80px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    color: #5D6168;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.profile-user-img {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 3px solid #d2d6de;
}

.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.datosGenerales {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT';
    text-align: center;
    color: #5D6168;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.puesto {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    color: #5D6168;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="box box-success">
                
                <div class="box-body">

                    <div class="actividades">Activity</div>
                    <div class="row box-body box-profile">
                        <div class="col-xs-5 col-lg-5"><img class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User profile picture"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-lg-7 text">
                                <div style="display:inline-block; text-align: left;" >
                                <h1><img class="profile-user-img  img-circle" style="width: 60px;" src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User profile picture"></h1></div>
                                <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:18px;color: blue;"class="pb-4">Blank</div>
                                <br>
                                <div style="display:inline-block; " >
                                <h1><img class="profile-user-img img-circle" style="width: 60px;" src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User profile picture"></h1></div>
                                <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:18px;color: blue;"class="pb-4"> Blank</div>
                                <br>
                                <div style="display:inline-block; " >
                                <h1><img class="profile-user-img  img-circle" style="width: 60px;" src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User profile picture"></h1></div>
                                <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:18px;color: blue;"class="pb-4"> Blank</div>
                            </div>  
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="datosGenerales">Name</h2>
                    <div class="puesto">Description</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
```